# Remove rows from column on whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining, data-cleaning

I want to keep all the rows in column, which has single word and rest of the rows which contains more than one white space to be removed.

My dataframe df is:

```
df['drug']
gilenya
fingolimod
ocrevus
dont want in the column
remove this drug row
text mining for drug column
```

I want to create a new dataframe with only correct drug words and removing the garbage. I have tried below solutions, but it gives me a blank/empty column of drug.

```
df_drug = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['drug'])
df_drug = df_drug[df_drug.drug.str.count(' ')==1]
or, df_drug = df_drug[df_drug.drug.str.contains('')]
```

Could you please help me to get the correct solution? Like:

```
df_drug.head()
drug
gilenya
fingolimod
ocrevus
```

Comment: `df[~df['drug'].str.contains(' ')]`.  Based on your definition, you want to remove even the rows that only have one whitespace. Or `df[~df['drug'].str.count(' ').gt(1)]` if it really is greater than one whitespace

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the rows which has more than one word. So, for a row containing actual "drug" name, would not have any white space(s). And the other rows, with garbage words should be removed from the rest of the rows in the column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function to return a boolean series that is only True where `df_drug['drug']` is one word, and then select from `df_drug` using that series.

```py
df_drug = df_drug[df_drug['drug'].apply(lambda x: True if len(x.split()) == 1 else False)]
```

If you have nans on the drug column, you might need to add something like `str(x)` to that lambda function.

Comment: Hi @Eva, I am getting an error KeyError: 'drug' what am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, make sure that there is actually a column named 'drug' in your dataframe. If you add code to your question to create some test input data I can help you debug.